# Required String parameter 'departure' is not present

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, freemarker

Required String parameter 'departure' is not present

**My controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String search(
                @RequestParam String departure,
                @RequestParam String arrival,
                @RequestParam String departureTime,
                Model model) {

            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            departureTime += " 00:00:00";  // departureTime = departureTime + " 00:00:00";
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(departureTime, formatter);

            Iterable<BusFlight> selects = busFlightService.getAll();
            List<BusFlight> busflights = busFlightService.search(departure, arrival, date);

            if (selects != null && busflights != null) {

                model.addAttribute("selects", selects);

                model.addAttribute("busflights", busflights);
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("busflights", "no flights");
            }
            return "search";
        }
```

**My FreeMarker Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"
</head>

<body style="background-color: #138496;">

<form action="/public/search" method="get">

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 200px">
<div class="row">
    <p>Click every input.</p>
</div>


    <div class="row">
  <span>
    <select name="departure" class="combobox input-large form-control" style="margin-right: 10px">
        <#list selects! as select>
            <option  value="${select.id}">${select.departure}</option>
        </#list>
    </select>
  </span>
    <span>
     <select name="arrival"  class="combobox input-large form-control">
        <#list selects! as select>
            <option  value="${select.id}">${select.arrival}</option>
        </#list>
     </select>
  </span>
    <span>
     <input type="date" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" value="2018-08-20"  name="departureTime"/>

        </span>
    <span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </span>
</div>
</div>



<#if busflights??>
<#list busflights as busflight >
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
<thead>
<tr>

        <th scope="col">Departure</th>
        <th scope="col">Arrival</th>
        <th scope="col">DepartureTime</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>

          <td>${busflight.departure}</td>
          <td>${busflight.arrival}</td>
          <td>${busflight.departureTime}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</#list>
<#else >
No buses
</#if>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.combobox').combobox()
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**My error:**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'departure' is not present
```

And one more question, is it possible to use GET request for one mapping "/search" and put it in client size ? like I tried in my case?

Also how I can rid of "Required String parameter 'departure' is not present"

Sanks

Comment: Are you selecting a departure value from the drop-down list before submitting? Your `<select>` template is not setting a `selected` element. As a result, you will not get a value for `departure` until you select one.

Answer (score 0):

1.it seem that your  tag not wrapper all the html controls, so put the

```
<form action="/public/search" method="get"> 
...
```

ahead of your **departure** input

2.put **departure** to your **select** control, not option, just like

```
<select name="departure">
```

the same for arrival

Comment: **<select name="departure" class="combobox input-large form-control" style="margin-right: 10px">**

Comment: **<select name="arrival"  class="combobox input-large form-control">**

Comment: _There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'departure' is not present_

Comment: same issue :(((

Comment: can you paste the html content entirely?

Comment: yep i just did ) in my topic message ) freemarker template

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>, change type to **submit**